# Unable to login Jenkins AWS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, aws-security-group

I am new to a specific Jenkins project. And in order to work on jenkins pipeline i need to login that instance. Now the previous devops guy had setup a system (he has left the organisation) where I need to login to another instance and then ssh to jenkins instance in aws.
So when I login to firs instance, it logins perfectly but when I ssh to jenkins instance it asks me for a passphrase. I have tried keeping it blank but not working. Is there any other way to ssh into this instance or any way that I can bypasss this passphrase?? May be by whitelisting elastic IP or something else.

I tried to enter various passphrases(which I can think of). The other possible solution I can find is whitelisting of elastic ip of that ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting to not enter a password, make sure you're using the correct username when connecting to the Jenkins instance. I think it's a good idea to check the shell history of the first instance to see how the previous DevOps person connected to the Jenkins instance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).